# Does Conformal Cyclic Cosmology imply a finite past?

Tags: cosmology

If I understand Roger Penrose's Conformal Cyclic Cosmology correctly, the previous eon comprised a universe conformal to ours with a smaller size and time-frame, at a finite point in the past.

If we add up the time duration of the infinite previous eons in the CCC model, do we arrive an asymptotically finite time in the past?

What can even be said, if anything, about the duration time duration or spacial size of previous eons (or future ones for that matter)?